# Finding angles for vectors and planes

Tags: vectors

my question is:

(1) How do I find the angle between the lines x -3 = 2 -y, z =1 and x=7, y-2 = z-5?

For (1), I have done the cross product but my answer is a decimal.

(2) How do I find the angle between the planes 2x + 3y + 3z = 0 and 3x-2y+4z-4=0

Comment: Your decimal answer can be converted to an angle by using
$$
\vec u\times \vec v = |\vec u|\cdot |\vec v| \cdot \sin(\alpha)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$1)$Cartesian equation of first line is $\frac {x-3}1=\frac {y-2}{-1}=\frac {z-1}0$ hence vector along this line is $(1,-1,0).$
 For second line, $\frac {x-7}0=\frac {y-2}1=\frac {z-5}1$. Hence vector along this line is $(0,1,1)$.
  Now simply calculate dot product of these two vectors i.e. $(1,-1,0)\cdot(0,1,1)=-1$. Also $||(1,-1,0)||=||(0,1,1)||=\sqrt 2$.
$\Rightarrow \cos\theta =\frac {(1,-1,0)\cdot(0,1,1)}{||(1,-1,0)||||(0,1,1)||}=\frac {-1}2$ $\Rightarrow \theta=\frac {2\pi}3$. Or we say acute angle between them is $\frac {\pi}3$ (simple calculation).

$2)$ For planes we calculate vector normal to each plane.
For first plane, normal vector is $(2,3,3)$ and for second one it is $(3,-2,4)$.
Here also dot product between both normal vectors is obtained by,
$\cos\theta=\frac {(2,3,3)\cdot(3,-2,4)}{||(2,3,3)||||(3,-2,4)||}=\frac {12}{(\sqrt 22)(\sqrt 29)}$. From here you can get $\theta$. That's the angle between two planes also.